# XML Deserializing

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I am doing xml string deserializing in to class. But it is not happening. Here is my sample xml:

```
<Transaction>
    <tag1 val1="1" val2="2">
        <subtag>somestring</subtag>
    </tag1>
<Transaction>
```

I have created class like this:

```
[Serialzable]
Class Transaction
{
    [xmlElement]
    public string tag1;
}

[Serialzable]
Class tag1
{
    [xmlAttribute]
    public string val1;
    [xmlAttribute]
    public string val2;

    [xmlAttribute]
    public string subtag;

}
```

Now when I'm deserializing, everything working correctly except subtag value. It's coming null into object. I tried to make it XMLElement and XMLAttribute both but no success.

Comment: Your end <Transaction> tag needs to be properly formatted:  `</Transaction>`

Answer (score 0):

Your Transaction class looks wrong: I think you mean the field to be `public tag1 tag1;`

You have the wrong attribute decorating the the subtag field in your `tag1` class definition. It is an element, not an attribute in your XML.

You also need to start with well-formed XML: your closing Transaction tag is missing a `/`

Comment: i missed the closing tag here. It is proper in my code. Also i tried subtag as XMlElement but no change in result. Still same issue. 

Thanks.

Comment: What language/serialization system are you using. I guessed .NET & C# (fixing up all your mistyping), and everything works so long as you use XmlElement for subtag.